# VS2005 error - Error retrieving information from user datastore

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, datastore

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 to compile c++ for WinCE device. (working on Win10) Compilation is working correctly but I'm gettin an error while attempting to connect to device directly (using static IP)

- *Error retreiving information from user datastore. Device not found.*

I've tried every solution I found (clearing Corecon directory, reseting settings on CE device and VS, reinstall of complete VS and SDK)

Could someone throw some light on this, please.